# bash script to read/ping a list of ip addresses from a text file and then write the results to another file?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a text file with a lists of IP addresses called address.txt which contains the following

```
172.26.26.1   wlan01

172.26.27.65    wlan02

172.26.28.180    wlan03
```

I need to write a bash script that reads the only IP addresses, ping them and output to a another text file to something like this:

> 172.26.26.1 IS UP
>
> 172.26.27.65 IS DOWN
>
> 172.26.28.180 IS DOWN

I am fairly new to bash scripting so I am not sure where to start with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux this would work:

```
awk '{print $1}' < address.txt | while read ip; do ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $ip IS UP || echo $ip IS DOWN; done
```

I don't have a cygwin now to test, but it should work there too.

Explanation:

- With `awk` we get the first column from the input file and pipe it into a loop
- We send a single `ping` to `$ip`, and redirect standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` so it doesn't pollute our output
- If `ping` is successful, the command after `&&` is executed: `echo $ip IS UP`
- If `ping` fails, the command after `||` is executed: `echo $ip IS DOWN`

Somewhat more readable, expanded format, to put in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{print $1}' < address.txt | while read ip; do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo $ip IS UP
    else
        echo $ip IS DOWN
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you explain this part? ">/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $ip IS UP || echo $ip IS DOWN; done" Where is it writing to?

Comment: How would I go about echoing the result to a new text file? Also it seems to be echo duplicate results.

Comment: You can redirect the result to a new file by sticking this to the end: `> newfile.out`. You would only see duplicate results if there are duplicate lines in `address.txt`. You can remove them by changing the first part to `sort -u address.txt | awk '{print $1}' | ...`

Comment: One final question, is there a way to format the results, they are in one line. I can fiddle with text window to see it better, but is there a more effective way?

Comment: There is one bit that can be written shorter: instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1` you could write `&>/dev/null` but that's a bit less portable. If you will need to do this often, I suggest to make it a proper shell script, and inside the script break it down to multiple lines. I'll add to my post nicely formatted, one sec.

Comment: I'm getiing this: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `done' Why?

Comment: Yup, copied word for word.

Comment: Yeah, I am in cygwin. The script does not do anything. When I run it, all I get is line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `done' line 8: `done'

Comment: Really, bizarre... If you run `wc` on your script, what do you get? (I will compare with what I have.)

Comment: I think your file has DOS-style line endings. Maybe that's ok in Windows, maybe not. It's best to remove the DOS-style line endings from your script file and try again. Do you have the `dos2unix` program in your `cygwin`? That would do it. Or else, hopefully this alternative will work: `tr -d '\r' < ping.sh > newping.sh`. If you run `wc` again on the new script you should see different count: `7 29 171`

Comment: I have dos2unix installed. I used tr -d '\r' < ping.sh > newping.sh and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: I got one more questiom about the script. Every IP I pinged seems to echoes IS DOWN. I even tried my own IP and it states down. I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean like this: **$ tr -d '\r' < address.txt > newaddress.txt** ? It still does not work.

Comment: Yup that's what I meant. Too bad. Next, if you run the ping line without the loop, does it work? `ping -c1 localhost && echo ok || echo down`

Comment: The purpose of `-c1` was to do just one ping, otherwise it would repeat forever. This is how it works in Linux and FreeBSD, I guess it's different in `cygwin`. I hope you can figure out the rest.